# Build Error in kotlinx-serialization w/ Retrofit 2

Tags: retrofit2, kotlinx.serialization

I am using kotlinx-serialization along with Retrofit, but when I build my project I get the following error:

> Your current kotlinx.serialization core version is too low, while
> current Kotlin compiler plugin 1.4.21 requires at least
> 1.0-M1-SNAPSHOT. Please update your kotlinx.serialization runtime dependency.

When I actually try to change my kotlinx-serialization dependency version to 1.0-M1-SNAPSHOT as the error suggests, I get a different error:

> Could not find
> org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.0-M1-SNAPSHOT.

Does anyone else have same issue? What was your workaround for it? So far, I've tried following [this article](https://www.ericthecoder.com/2020/11/16/getting-started-with-kotlinx-serialization/) and [this Medium post](https://medium.com/swlh/kotlinx-serialization-part1-4407893132c2) and this [github discussion](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/993), but none have worked for me. Any help is much appreciated! Below is my set up:

#### The App

```
@Serializable
data class TimeSeriesRequest(
    val functoin,
    val symbol,
    val inteval,
    val apikey
)
```

#### build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

#### build.gradle (Module)

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.applicatoin"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "kotlinx-serialization"
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.2.0"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:0.5.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to
`implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:1.0-M1-1.4.0-rc"`

Where you're using `Json.parse()` change it to `Json.decodeFromString()`, same arguments.

Going forward, the version numbers are in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-serialization-runtime?repo=kotlinx